# Why has the model backing the <contextclass> context changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

We're using code first with EF5 in an MVC application.

The model was created (for reasons I won't go into) in a test harness.  Then, when I try to access the dbcontext in the web app I get an invalidoperationexception stating that the model backing the  context has changed.

There is no schema difference at all.  In fact, I've created the database from both within the test harness & within the web app.  When it's created within the web app it's fine, when it's created in another program and accessed in the web app it fails.

I notice that there is a binary representation of the model in the _MigrationHistory.  I've compared this for both database creation methods and it's always the same.

What exactly does EF check to determine that the model has changed because as far as I can see everything is identical & should work either way  but it doesn't which leads me to think that I'm missing something here.

Comment: may be you are not talking to the same database?

Comment: No, definitely the same database.  I've double checked everything like that.

Comment: Do you have any migrations that reference the DbContext directly? I ran into this issue and blogged about it: http://bit.ly/ef-migrations-gotcha